# Devise - Pass custom parameters, not through Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, devise

I want to be able to pass parameters from the point a visitor decides to register manual (not with omniauth).

I have tried to customize devise own controller but with no luck. I have experience uninitialized constants...

So now I'm back on square one. how can I pass a custom parameter and pick it up once the user been registered and signed in?

I'm on Ruby On Rails '3.2.13'.

Comment: do you want to persist this in the database? or just have access to it in the session?

Comment: Only in the session, I will use it to update another model. I have thought of creating a session var that I can access later on. Maybe thats the thing I should do.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more explicit, are you trying to pass a custom parameter to the registration page, (i.e., when they hit the register link). Or are you trying to pass a custom parameter along with the form post?